# Why doesn't git allow me to safely delete a branch?

Tags: git, merge, branch

I needed to merge two branches -- `second` into `first` and then get rid of `second`.  Here's what I did:

- `git clone`d the project to get a fresh copy
- `git checkout --track origin/second`, made some changes, and committed
- `git checkout --track origin/first`, made some changes, and committed
- `git merge second` (git says "merge made by recursive")
- `git branch -d second`

Then git says:

```
$ git branch -d second
warning: not deleting branch 'second' that is not yet merged to
         'refs/remotes/origin/second', even though it is merged to HEAD.
error: The branch 'second' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D second'.
```

Why is this happening?  I've never gotten this message after a merge before.  The merge worked just fine, no conflicts.  How do I safely delete the `second` branch?

Comment: `git checkout second` followed by `git push origin second` makes git stop complaining, but I don't understand why.

Comment: A wild guess, but maybe git complains that you have not pushed `second` to origin before deleting it? Also make sure you are not in »detached HEAD« state

Comment: @knittl yes, you seem to be right, but why would git care whether I've pushed `second`?

Comment: It doesn't want you to loose local-only changes to a remote branch (Although, I've never seen that message myself). I'll dig around in the source to find the logic behind it.

Comment: In this case, it knows that `second` is a tracking branch for `origin/second`, so it wants to know that changes done on `second` have been pushed to `origin`. If it was not a tracking branch, I don't think it would complain about this. The fact that `second` has been merged into `first` locally doesn't seem to be important to `git` at this point, although it seems you could probably make the case that since it has at least been merged into something else, deleting the branch should be acceptable.

Comment: If you are sure you have everything you need from that branch you can use the -D option to force the delete

Comment: @MattFenwick whats the output of git branch --contains second? Does it say that the branch is completely merged?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'd already made a bunch more changes so I wasn't able to try that.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Based on my experiments and @knittl's and @twalberg's comments, it seems that git just wanted me to push my changes to the `second` branch before deleting it.

I did:

```
$ git checkout second
$ git push origin second
$ git checkout first
$ git branch -d second
```

which worked without warnings.

Comment: Wouldn't `git branch -D second` solve it as well or is that a dangerous practice?

Comment: @Bart it depends on what you mean by "solve it".  Doing that would not have the same result as my solution -- the state of the `origin` remote would be different.

Comment: @Bart that should only be used when you know what you're doing. Git mostly gives helpful warnings, so it's always better to not force things on it.

Comment: @Bart for a new user (like me) 'push origin' is more acceptable than removing the branch by force.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the local "second" branch is not synced with the remote "second" branch, and git does not want you to lose any work.

In this situation, the update is not sure to get lost because it has already merged to "HEAD". If the "HEAD" branch is pushed to remote, there should not be a problem. However, if there is something wrong with "HEAD", there still is a chance you lose your work

To conclude, it just an extra guarantee, feel free to forcibly delete.

Answer (score 0):

I think this actually happens when you have merged a branch on the remote (i.e. via a `Pull Request`) and deleted the remote branch.

In my experiment **not** deleting the remote branch and using `-d` locally **FIRST** is the solution.